# Ruby on Rails- ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished on localhost:3000

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm a Ruby on Rails beginner, following the online book [Ruby on Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/beginning#sec-version_control).  When I do `bundle update` and `bundle install` and then `rails server`

When I connect to localhost:3000/, I get the following image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NOEn.png
The GemFile I used has this content:

```
    source 'http://rubygems.org'

    gem 'rails', '3.1.1'

    gem 'sqlite3'

    group :development do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
    end


    group :test do
      gem 'rspec-rails', '2.6.1'
      gem 'webrat', '0.7.1'
    end

    group :assets do
      gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.1.4'
      gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.1.1'
      gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
    end

    gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Update: Database.yml file looks like this

```
# SQLite version 3.x
#   gem install sqlite3
#
#   Ensure the SQLite 3 gem is defined in your Gemfile
#   gem 'sqlite3'
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/test.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

production:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/production.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

The Full Trace on the localhost page gives the following output:

```
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:409:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:107:in `retrieve_connection'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in `connection'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:65:in `rescue in call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:59:in `call'
activerecord (3.1.1) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:477:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:392:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:68:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:101:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:48:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:47:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:13:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
activesupport (3.1.1) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
actionpack (3.1.1) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/engine.rb:456:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/content_length.rb:16:in `call'
railties (3.1.1) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
rack (1.3.10) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
```

Comment: What does your config/database.yml file look like?

Comment: Ensure you have sqlite3 installed

Comment: Updated to include database.yml.  And how do I install sqlite3?

Comment: Please paste a textual error message into your question, so it will be of benefit to others, and remove the screenshot.

Comment: Did you do a rake db:create? what do you see when you run `sqlite3` in console?

Comment: Rails 3.1.1 most likely is incompatible with latest sqlite. Use 3.2.13.

Answer (score 0):

Add the line `gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.5'` inside the `development:` section in your Gemfile. Then run `bundle install`